# Android Retrofit AES encrypt/decrypt POST and Response

Tags: android, encryption, aes, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit 2.0

I want to encrypt my @body example the User Object

```
@POST("users/new")
Call<User> createUser(@Body User newUser);
```

and then decrypt the response .

what is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 9):

Use `Interceptor`s to encrypt the body.

```
public class EncryptionInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private static final String TAG = EncryptionInterceptor.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final boolean DEBUG = true;

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        RequestBody oldBody = request.body();
        Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
        oldBody.writeTo(buffer);
        String strOldBody = buffer.readUtf8();

        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        String strNewBody = encrypt(strOldBody);
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, strNewBody);
        request = request.newBuilder().header("Content-Type", body.contentType().toString()).header("Content-Length", String.valueOf(body.contentLength())).method(request.method(), body).build();

        return chain.proceed(request);
    }

    private static String encrypt(String text) {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Then add the `Interceptor` to the Retrofit:

```
client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addNetworkInterceptor(new EncryptionInterceptor()).build();
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().client(client).build();
```

More about `Interceptor`s: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors

Comment: CodeMachine.encrypt(strOldBody)   what is CodeMachine?

Comment: @MuhammadHaroon probably a remnant from the answerer's project. I've fixed the code to use the class' `encrypt()` method instead.

Comment: @AndrewT. sir please can you tell me about how to get encrypted AES response in android using retrofit.